# R-Python Reticulate : TypeError: 'size' must be an integer

Tags: r, reticulate

New to Reticulate, I'm trying to run this sample code with no luck :(

```
library(reticulate)
use_virtualenv("~/virtualenv", required = TRUE)
np <- import("numpy", convert = FALSE)
plt <- import("matplotlib.pyplot")
img <- import("pyts")

# R variables
image_data <- runif(25)
reshape_image_data <- array_reshape(image_data, c(25,1))

# Reticulated Python variables
x_array <- np$array(reshape_image_data)

mtf <- img$image$MTF(c(5, 5))
#mtf <- img$image$MTF(as.integer(c(as.integer(5),as.integer(5))))

X_mtf <- mtf$fit_transform(x_array)
```

Get this error :

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: 'size' must be an integer.

Detailed traceback: 
  File "~/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 517, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "~/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyts/image/image.py", line 268, in transform
    raise TypeError("'size' must be an integer.")
```

This comes from pyts.image.image.py where check code looks like :

```
if not isinstance(self.image_size, int):
            raise TypeError("'size' must be an integer.")
```

Did not get it to work. Anybody tried ?
Thanx

Comment: After which line in your R code do you get the error?

Comment: Does the actual Python code of a 1-D numpy array with shape `(25, 1)` work with this code?

Comment: @divibisan the error occurs after last line of code

Comment: @Parfait +1 should be `(1, 25)`

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it. Pay attention to `array_reshape c(1,25)` and `MTF as.integer(5)`
:

```
library(reticulate)
use_virtualenv("~/virtualenv", required = TRUE)
np <- import("numpy", convert = FALSE)
plt <- import("matplotlib.pyplot")
img <- import("pyts")

# R variables
image_data <- runif(25)
reshape_image_data <- array_reshape(image_data, c(1,25))

# Reticulated Python variables
x_array <- np$array(reshape_image_data)

mtf <- img$image$MTF(as.integer(5))

X_mtf <- mtf$fit_transform(x_array)
```

Comment: Btw, you didn't need `array_reshape` as R has `matrix` call: `matrix(runif(25), nrow=25, ncol=1)`. Be sure to always `set.seed(###)` any random number calls to reproduce results.